# How to find out if a struct is present in a vector of structs by a variable within the struct

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I want to check if an element is present in the vector or not. I searched for answers and I found this

```
if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) != vector.end())
    do_this();
else
    do_that();
```

What if the vector is of type structure. Can we still use this to find if there is match in the vector. I want to find in the vector using the field id in the struct entry. Is it possible??

```
struct entry {
    int id;
    int array[4] = {};
    int aray[4] = {};
};
```

Comment: Did you try using it for a `struct`? What issues did you face?

Comment: I used it with struct. No issues. What I want to do is to find in vector, a struct with id = 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `std::find_if()`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](S s) { return 5 == s.id; } );
if (vec.end() != it)
    do_this(); // it now points to the S instance found in the vector
else
    do_that();
```

Comment: How to refer to that particular element. Does this return an iterator pointing to the entry?

Comment: ^Updated the answer.

Comment: Thats so simple and working. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much